# jquery's .serialize is sending GET not POST

Tags: php, html, jquery

I got a problem here, when I used ajax to send a form it works fine but the URL became like this:

[image]

is this really common when using:

```
$j.post("sendMail.php", $j("#formMail").serialize());
```

because I want the page's Url the same as it is without having those extensions in the URL.

Comment: What want to do a form post vs a get request?

Comment: Just a wild guess.. maybe there is a javascript error on the page and the event binding is not working fine for submit/click event .. Check for any JS errors on the page.

Comment: have u tried this with $.param too? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/

Comment: Your form is being submitted with "get" method in the foreground. You must "return false" within the jquery function that handles the form submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$j("#formMail").on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```